# MySQL one-to-many mapping query - if match on many, do not return one

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table like this:

```
+----------+--------+
| brand    | vehicle|
+----------+--------+
|  ford    |    car | 
|  ford    |  truck | 
|  ford    |    suv | 
+----------+--------+
```

I want to write a single query that only returns the brand when all 3 rows have met the conditions. For example, if I say "give me the brand that has car, but not truck or suv", I expect the query to return nothing since "ford" has all 3. Unfortunately the query as I have constructed doesn't work:

```
SELECT brand 
  FROM table 
 WHERE vehicle='car' 
   AND vehicle != 'truck' 
   AND vehicle != 'suv';
```

The query returns "ford". I understand why it did that. It tested the conditions against each row, and row 1 passed, so the brand from row 1 is returned. But how can I construct a query to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most generalizable way to do that, which allows to check for arbitrary number of conditions, is to put your conditions in `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT brand 
  FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY brand
HAVING MAX(vehicle = 'car') = 1 
   AND MAX(vehicle = 'truck') = 0
   AND MAX(vehicle = 'suv') = 0;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d0a3/1)** demo

Comment: can i use this query instead of using max() SELECT brand , vehicle
  FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY brand
HAVING vehicle = 'car' 
   AND vehicle <> 'truck'
   AND vehicle <> 'suv';

Comment: No you can't: 1) `vehicle = 'car'` is a boolean expression that returns `0` (false) or `1` (true) 2) you have to apply an aggregate function to your expression in `HAVING` clause

Comment: i was just curious about how stuff works, not OP of the question. but ur solution does solve the issue andd i think OP must accept ur answer

Answer (score 2):

You would need to join against the same table for *each* condition

```
SELECT t1.brand
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON (t1.brand = t2.brand AND t2.vehicle = 'truck')
LEFT JOIN table t3 ON (t1.brand = t3.brand AND t3.vehicle = 'suv')
WHERE t1.vehicle = 'car' AND t2.brand IS NULL AND t3.brand IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5a06/3